# Facebook FQL - Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-fql

I am running the following Facebook FQL for my iOS app. It is giving me the error:

```
**Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)**
```

I have tested the permissions and they seem to be fine. Also the bundle id in the facebook app (on the developers section) matches the bundle id on the app. How do I fix this issue ?

```
NSString *query =
@"SELECT recipient_id, title_text, notification_id, object_id FROM notification WHERE recipient_id = me() and is_unread = 1";
// Set up the query parameter
NSDictionary *queryParam =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];
// Make the API request that uses FQL
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                              notifications = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                              //NSLog(@"%d", [array count]);
                              NSString *notificationPressed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"   %d     unread notifications", [notifications count]];
                              [self.fliteController say:notificationPressed withVoice:self.slt];

                          }
                      }];
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error message on the simulator, because my app has been blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what leads you to believe this is a firewall issue by providing supporting evidence about port configuration, etc.

Comment: I'm using TCPBlock. Moving my app from the blocked list to the white list solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem due to authentication, I changed the password of my Facebook account in browser and selected sign out from all the devices. Signing in again in iPhone settings solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. What happened is that on my iPhone I had two email addresses in conflict, and had to go through my phone to find the email addy's that I no longer used. Thank you to Charlie, you set me on the right path. My problem was with Instagram not posting to FB. Thanks!